# What is the accuracy of the wossip app?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

what is the accuracy of the wossip app`s USAGE menu drop down? Does it reflect actual usage of the monitored account or some other state?

Comment: From the reviews it doesn't seem to be too accurate.